# Why does the ScheduledService from javaFX not work with a concrete class as Task?

Tags: java, javafx

I was working on my JavaFX application when i noticed that on ScheduledService stopped being scheduled after a couple of runs.

I was not able to find any obvious reason for this. When i tracked that state of the ScheduledService it seemed that it switched to the the state SCHEDULED and then went silent.
I reduced my code to almost nothing in the hope to narrow down the issue. I discovered that when i ScheduledService creates a Task of an anonymos class, the issue does not occur but when i use sub class or top level class it does.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static volatile int counter;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage )
    {
        ScheduledService<Void> svc = new ScheduledService<>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask()
            {
                return new MyTask();// if i use new Task<Void>{...} it works fine
            }
        };
        svc.start();
    }

    private static class MyTask extends Task<Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println( "MyTask#call() " + counter++ );
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }
}
```

The output

```
MyTask#call() 0
MyTask#call() 1
MyTask#call() 2
MyTask#call() 3
MyTask#call() 4
MyTask#call() 5
MyTask#call() 6
MyTask#call() 7
MyTask#call() 8
MyTask#call() 9
MyTask#call() 10
MyTask#call() 11
MyTask#call() 12
MyTask#call() 13
MyTask#call() 14
```

Is this a bug?

I'm Using

Windows 10

OracleOpen_jdk-12.0.1

javafx-sdk-12.0.1

Comment: Works for me on Java 8; I don't have Java 12 installed to test it.  BTW, this is the epitome of what a [mcve] should be.  Congrats on an excellent first post.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with java 11 either, but it's suspicious that `start` doesn't show any GUI. On java 11 the service immediately shuts down after closing the main stage shown in the `start` method. Something like this may be happening to you (Application shutdown after `start`, since no windows are shown).

Comment: I could reproduce with Java 7 and 8 but I have no explanation yet.. I don't think the application strictly shuts down. And still I observe random results...: sometimes it happens to behave well for a long period of time. I believe that the default behavior of the service (period=0) could be too intensive.. Empirically I could see that setting a service period of at least 10ms gives better results: it will let it run far more time but some runs still crash. That's all I have for now... I have issues with my profiler so I cannot really tell more.. ;)

Comment: I'm guessing since you keep no reference to `svc` it gets garbage-collected at some point.

Comment: I think that's it @Itai . When my ScheduledService is a member field instead of a local one it works fine. I'm still a bit confused why it works with a anonymous class then. I mean in my example the class MyTask is static but even when it is not it does not work. Objects of a non-static inner class should have a reference to there outer class objects. So i would think non-static inner classes and anonymous classes should work the same in this situation. Thanks tho

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce the problem using the following environment:

- Windows 10
- OpenJDK 12.0.1
- OpenJFX 12.0.1

Modifying the code slightly shows you what the problem is:

```
import java.lang.ref.Cleaner;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final Cleaner CLEANER = Cleaner.create();
    private static final AtomicInteger COUNTER = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var service = new ScheduledService<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new MyTask();
            }

        };
        CLEANER.register(service, () -> {
            System.out.println("SERVICE GARBAGE COLLECTED!");
            System.exit(0);
        });
        service.start();
    }

    private static class MyTask extends Task<Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception{
            System.out.println("MyTask#call() " + COUNTER.incrementAndGet());
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

The above outputs:

```
MyTask#call() 1
MyTask#call() 2
MyTask#call() 3
MyTask#call() 4
MyTask#call() 5
MyTask#call() 6
MyTask#call() 7
MyTask#call() 8
MyTask#call() 9
MyTask#call() 10
MyTask#call() 11
MyTask#call() 12
MyTask#call() 13
MyTask#call() 14
MyTask#call() 15
MyTask#call() 16
MyTask#call() 17
MyTask#call() 18
MyTask#call() 19
SERVICE GARBAGE COLLECTED!
```

So that explains what is happening—the `ScheduledService` instance is being garbage collected. This makes sense since you don't maintain a strong reference to the `ScheduledService` instance and neither does the `Task` instance being executed. Once the `ScheduledService` instance is garbage collected it can't schedule another `Task` for the next execution cycle.

---

> I'm still a bit confused why it works with a anonymous class then. I mean in my example the class MyTask is static but even when it is not it does not work. Objects of a non-static inner class should have a reference to there outer class objects.

It's true that a non-static nested or anonymous class maintains a reference to an instance of the enclosing class. However, the enclosing class is `Main` (`MyApplication` in your code), not the anonymous `ScheduledService` class.

---

> ```
> return new MyTask();// if i use new Task<Void>{...} it works fine
> ```

The reason using `new Task<Void>() { ... }` works is because now the enclosing instance is the `ScheduledService` instance.

The `ScheduledService` class uses an internal `java.util.Timer` instance for scheduling the `Task` for later execution. So while waiting to be executed the `Task` is strongly reachable by the thread used by the `Timer`. While being executed, the `Task` is strongly reachable by the thread executing it (the thread comes from the `Executor` used with in `ScheduledService#executor` property).

So, when using an anonymous `Task` enclosed by the anonymous `ScheduledService`, the `ScheduledService` is ultimately strongly reachable.

- Scheduling/Executing Thread → Task → ScheduledService

---

<s>Curiously, if I add code to display the primary `Stage` the `ScheduledService` is never garbage collected. I'm not sure why this is the case. This is true even when I use `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)` and close the `Stage`.</s>